# Is it commonly accepted to refer to a Master Degree in Statistics as M.Stat.?

Tags: masters, degree, statistics

I have recently obtained a Master Degree in Statistics from Tor Vergata University of Rome.

Can I routinely use the term M.Stat., which has the strength of being much more specific and informative, or is it more appropriate to use the generic M.Sc. term?

Comment: 'MSc Statistics' or 'MSc in Statistics' I'ld say

Comment: I see. The issue is that typically I sign already myself as Giuseppe Biondi-Zoccai, MD. Should I add to MD, also MSc, or MStat, or MSc Statistics?

Answer (score 7):

You can only use the degree that is displayed on your certificate. I am not aware of any case in which one can make up one's own academic degree just for convenience. The only case of something similar would be when it comes to international adaptations (e.g. the German "Dr." is equivalent to a PhD (except the Dr. med.)). By using "M.stat." you would imply that you received this specific degree, which you did not. In my opinion this would be fraud.

Comment: Note that in Germany, [you cannot simply use a "Dr." if you have a Ph.D.](http://www.lto.de/recht/studium-referendariat/s/auslaendische-titel-anerkennung-doktor-tschechien/)

Comment: The problem is that in Italy neither MSc nor MStat is given in English terms, so I have to translate it. As it is a Master in Statistics (Master in Statistica), I was wondering how best to convey its focus and scope, not trying to fool anybody.

Comment: Stephan Kolassa, I am afraid that this is not entirely true. In your citation the person did not have a PhD! The German law allows "Dr." to be used for a wide variety of international PhDs: https://www.kmk.org/fileadmin/Dateien/pdf/ZAB/Gradfuehrung_Beschluesse_der_KMK/20150626_KMK-Beschluss_Beguenstigende_Regelungen.pdf

Comment: Giuseppe Biondi-Zoccai: What is commonly done is to write the degree in its original form (i.e. Master in Statistica) and then either indicate the length of the studies (e.g. "five year degree") or indicate the anglo saxon equivalent, which in your case does not exist as far as I am aware.

Comment: @Chris: I actually found some evidence that an M Stat exists in other countries, eg http://statistics.rice.edu/Content_MStat.aspx?id=2147483904 in the UK and http://www.isibang.ac.in/~statmath/courses/mstatbro.htm in India. That's why I would favor using it.

Comment: @GiuseppeBiondi-Zoccai: An MStat in the UK is not only not the same as an MSc in statistics, it's actually a less valuable qualification!